# Adding users to list from group in Active Directory but crashing when adding .tostring

Tags: c#

I've got code that connects to Active Directory and finds the correct group. when I try to add to a `List<string>`it crashes. exception is it throws `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

```
public static List<string> user_List(string group_Name)
        {
            using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "myDomainName"))
            {

                using (var group =GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, group_Name))
                {

                    List<string> myList = null;

                    if (group == null)
                    {                      
                        myList.Add("No User Defined");                        
                        return myList;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        var users = group.GetMembers(true);                       

                        foreach (var user in users)
                        {

                            if (user == null) return myList;
                            myList.Add(user.ToString());
              // if I use :System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(user.ToString()); message box shows with test 1 test 2 and test 3
                        }
                        return myList;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: `it crashes.` How? Does it throw an exception? Does it give you any kind of error message?

Comment: This really needs more detail, but answerers have correctly surmised that the code in question throws a `NullReferenceException` due to myList not being instantiated.

Comment: I'm sorry I'll edit my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare your `myList` variable here:

```
 List<string> myList = null;
```

But you never actually assign an instance of a list to it. So you get a `NullReferenceException` when you try to add. You can't add an item to a list that doesn't exist!

You need to actually create a list:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 2):

Your line

```
List<string> myList = null;
```

defines a reference to a list, but no list object. It will crash with an exception! Simply define a list:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
 List<string> myList = null;
```

To

```
 List<string> myList = new List<string>();
```

Eplanation :

You cannot add a string value to null as this result in `NullReferenceException`